# Testing convergence of a series using the limit of a different sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

This is a problem adapted from Stewart Calculus, and I feel like the provided solution is too hand-wavy to be satisfactory.

Suppose $\{b_n\}$ is a sequence that converges to $\frac{1}{5}$. The goal is to determine whether or not $\sum \frac{b_n^n}{n}$ converges, using the ratio test.

If we let $a_n = \frac{b_n^n}{n}$, then $$a_{n+1} = \frac{b_{n+1}^{n+1}}{n+1}.$$ Applying the ratio test to evaluate the the limit of $| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|$ as $n$ goes to infinity, we get

$$b_{n+1} (\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n})^n \cdot \frac{n}{n+1}.$$

Taking the limit, $b_{n+1}$ becomes $\frac{1}{5}$ and $\frac{n}{n+1}$ becomes $1$, but I don't know how to address the factor in the middle. It's a mistake to say that we can take the limit inside before taking the limit on the outside-- after all, $\lim_{x \to \infty} ({1 + 1/x})^x$ is $e$, not $1$.

What is the right way to do this problem?

Comment: The instructions are that you *must* use the Ratio Test?

Comment: Indeed, you cannot just take the limit in the middle. For instance, if $b_{2n} = 1/5+1/\sqrt{n}$ and $b_{2n+1} = 1/5$, look at what you'd get. Again, are you sure you need to use the ratio test?

Comment: The solution (which is hand-wavy to the point of being incorrect) uses the ratio test. Unfortunately I suppressed some information about the problem for the sake of simplicity and not copying from the book-- it was actually an alternating series.

Comment: @NoName I don't see how adding an alternating sign would help in any way with the ratio test. Did you mean instead that $(b_n)_n$ was assumed monotone? More generally, you may want (possibly in a new question) to give the actual statement. This one, as my answer show, is not amenable to the ratio test.

Comment: Well, the ratio test suppresses sign. The comparison test doesn't work immediately because the terms aren't all positive, although it may work to prove absolute convergence. I'm trying to work through your solution now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **cannot** use the ratio test for that, it is inconclusive. For instance, consider the sequence $(b_n)_n$ defined by

$$
b_{2n}=\frac{1}{5},\qquad b_{2n+1}=\frac{1}{5}\left(1+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)
$$
for all $n\geq 0$. Then
$$
\frac{a_{2n+1}}{a_{2n}} = \frac{1}{5}\cdot \frac{2n}{2n+1}\cdot \left(1+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^{2n+1} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \infty
$$
while
$$
\frac{a_{2n+2}}{a_{2n+1}} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0
$$
so the ratio test is inconclusive (the limit of the ratio fails to exist).

*Other tests, like comparison to say $(9/10)^n/n$, will work, though, since $|b_n| \leq 9/10$ for all $n$ large enough.*